# Bonding in molten silicon dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Solid silicon dioxide has a giant lattice structure with single covalent bonds, while in the gas phase it has a molecular carbon dioxide-like structure. But what about in the liquid phase?

Would it be formed of molecules as well, or are there still only single covalent bonds that form and reform? Or is it more like metallic bonding with delocalized electrons? Or something else entirely?

Comment: You might look at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11663-014-0092-1.pdf and see if that helps.

Comment: It´s surely not metallic. ;)

Comment: :/ Just about like in glass, only less and less interlinking bonds with rising temperature. Close to boiling point there would a lot of small molecules, I guess.

Comment: @Mithoron - a light perusal of the thermodynamic modeling literature suggests that the pure SiO2 liquid remains almost exclusively O-Si-O entities, unlike other oxides that will have a variety of components (one could imagine O-Si, O or O2, etc. being conceivable, but they are not really seen in the liquid). Now, add another oxide and things start getting interesting quickly.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not sure what you mean. It's clearly a variety of structures comprising varying number of SiO4 tetrahedra.  What would be " O-Si, O or O2, etc." though? If there was Na+, the units would be just smaller and more or less anionic. With, Pb, it would indeed be more interesting.

Comment: @Mithoron - well, it gets pretty esoteric quickly unless one loves phase diagram modeling. In a variety of pure binary phase diagrams, as well as complex oxide systems, one has to take into account a variety of possible short-range ordering that may be energetically favorable. For example, in Na$_{2}$O-Al$_{2}$O$_{3}$, the model of the liquid is NaO$_{0.5}$, AlO$_{1.5}$, and an "associate" NaAlO$_{2}$. At a given temperature and composition, the relative ratios of the three entities can be calculated. Other oxides may have multiple species in the melt as indicated by XRD measurements.